# Using javascript var in jQuery .html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simple question:

Is it possible to display a var in .html, using jQuery?

```
var inscr = '<?php echo "test"; ?>';
    $j('#myPlaceHolder7').html('<li class="button3">+inscr</li>');
```

Thanks!

Thanks everyone for the quick help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup:

```
$j('#myPlaceHolder7').html('<li class="button3">' + inscr + '</li>');
```

Just concatenate your var with the enclosing strings, using the `+` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the `+` operator to concatenate the strings.

```
var inscr = '<?php echo "test"; ?>';
$j('#myPlaceHolder7').html('<li class="button3">' + inscr + '</li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yah, try this:

```
var inscr = '<?php echo "test"; ?>';
$j('#myPlaceHolder7').html('<li class="button3">' + inscr + '</li>');
```

Now if your var is not a string or simple type, you will need a util to searialize the var.  Try JSON2's stringify.  This will show your object as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var inscr = <?php echo json_encode("test"); ?>;
$j('#myPlaceHolder7').html('<li class="button3">'+inscr+'</li>');
</script>
```

Results in this source:

```
<script>
var inscr = "test";
$j('#myPlaceHolder7').html('<li class="button3">'+inscr+'</li>');
</script>
```

See [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)